# Personal Access Token in .git config

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I was getting this error when trying to pull from gitlab.

> remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied.
>
> The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token instead of a password.

I don't have 2FA and found this solution to work:

- https://debugah.com/solved-sourcetree-pull-code-error-remote-http-basic-access-denied-15652/

Now my token is inside of the config file in .git.

I know that .git has enough information to restore the whole project from scratch. So if I push the project, will that expose my token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Files inside the *git dir* (.git) are not tracked, Only the stuff from the *work tree*. Try cloning from the current repo to another folder on your machine. You will not find the token in the new clone - same for pushing.

e.g.

```
git clone C:\my-git D:\clone-of-my-git
```